# Dataloader Command line issue for version 37

Tags: data-loader

am upgrading from version 33 due to the TLS 1.0 deprecation and my script is no longer working. updated the jar version but am getting the following java error now.

> C:\CustomerGrid\bin>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data
>   Loader"\jav a\bin\java.exe -cp "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader"\dataloade r-37.0.0-uber.jar
>   -Dsalesforce.config.dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com \Data Loader\groupContactExtract\config"
>   com.salesforce.dataloader.process.Proce ssRunner
>   process.name=groupContactExtract Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/salesforc
>   e/dataloader/process/ProcessRunner : Unsupported major.minor version
>   52.0
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the main class: com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner. 
>   Program will exit.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the version of Java on your machine is too old to run the new version of the data loader and you need to upgrade it to Java 1.8 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html).

If you want to know the specifics of why it doesn't work, the clue is " Unsupported major.minor version 52.0". This means that the data loader Java bytecode is stamped with bytecode version 52, which is Java 1.8 and your JVM does not know how to interpret this bytecode. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I don't quite understand how they modified the java call, but I had luck handing control to the process.bat file that comes with the Data Loader install:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin"
process.bat "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\ProcessConfDirectory" BeanName
```

...you should, of course, modify the specifics in the above two lines to accommodate your needs.

I can tell that the latest process.bat calls the java.exe in the %JAVA_HOME%\bin directory. I don't know what else it's doing.

Good luck!